# React useEffect deps being called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have this effect:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!maximumTocAttemptsExceeded) {
    if (!isLoading) {
      console.log('Here I need to reach');
    }
  }
}, [isLoading, error]);
```

My doubt is:

If `error` value (that comes as a prop each time that the component is rendered) changes, will the useEffect get executed? But I'm not using its value inside the useEffect. And, `maximumTocAttemptsExceeded` comes from props too, do I need to put it as a dependency on the hook?

My useEffect is being triggered way more times than I need it. It's supposed to be executed only when error is defined

Comment: so error is only going to change once?

Comment: error comes from an API from a parent component. error by default is null, but sometimes is an object, so each time that error exists, I need to reach that console.log on useEffect

Comment: **It's suposes to be executed only when error is defined** => your dependency is only error, isLoading and maximumTocAttemptsExceeded are not because they don't trigger useEffect. With your current code, if error or isLoading change then useEffect will be called

Comment: It's all ok now, maybe the question should be closed. my `error` prop wasn't chaning, I had to chain another error (a redux error) to my `error` constant, and there only with [error] as a dep the useEffect ws called as expected. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

If this is the effect you need to run:

```
if (!maximumTocAttemptsExceeded) {
  if (!isLoading) {
    console.log('Here I need to reach');
  }
}
```

You **should** add **only** `maximumTocAttemptsExceeded` and `isLoading` to your dependency array.

**Why?**

Because React will always keep your effects up-to-date. So if you are using those variables, React assumes that if one of those variables change, it should re-run your effect code so you'll get an up-to-date effect on your component.

If `error` has got anything to do to your effect code, you should use it and add it to the dependency array as well.

Example:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (error) {
    if (!maximumTocAttemptsExceeded) {
      if (!isLoading) {
        console.log('Here I need to reach');
      }
    }
  }
}, [isLoading, error,maximumTocAttemptsExceeded]);
```

Be aware that React does only shallow comparisons on those reference values. So if any of the variables in the dependency array is an object or array which is being recreated on every render, your effect will run on every render. Because although the content of those objects could be the same from previous render, their references change when they are recreated. So, if you your effect depends on a property of an object, you should use only that, and add it to the dependency array as `obj.prop`, so React will know that you depend on a single `prop` of the object instead of the whole object.